# create new column in dataframe which returns the number of records recorded each day

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe with date which resembles the following:

df =

```
ID      date
124     2022-03-14
34      2022-03-14
66      2022-03-14
2       2022-03-15
91      2022-03-16
20      2022-03-16
```

I'm trying to add a new column to the df which would state the number of records we have for each day. So the output should look like this:

```
ID      date          daily_records
124     2022-03-14    3
34      2022-03-14    3
66      2022-03-14    3
2       2022-03-15    1
91      2022-03-16    2
20      2022-03-16    2
```

I've tried using:

```
df['daily_records] = df.groupby('date').count()
```

But it just returns NaN values. How could I get my desired outcome

Comment: `groupby().transform()`: `df['daily_records'] = df.groupby('date')['date'].transform('count')`.

Comment: The NaNs come up as the series df.groupby('date').count() has completely different indices to your original dataframe and that makes sense. I mean, your series for the example given will span three entries, so how should pandas know how to generate a new column out of this in your original dataframe? Really, what you want is to merge the result from the right hand side, to the left based on the key 'date'.